# Expecting one line in output file but getting more

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell, and I am stumped. I am trying to generate a listing of files in all subdirectories starting in some specific top folder, outputting the result to a text file, or better yet a CSV file. For example, assume I have a folder called "TEST", which has a subfolder called "A". Each of these folders has some text files.

I've tried the following:

```
$path='c:\users\x\desktop\TEST'
$files=get-childitem $path -recurse
foreach($file in $files){
$file.fullname, $file.lastwritetime | out-file -append c:\users\x\desktop\output.txt
}
```

The resulting output for each file is split among two lines, the first being the full filename & path, the second being the Day, Month, Year, and time.
I just can't figure out how to get both of these properties to appear on the same line as:

```
c:\users\x\test\file1.txt, last modified date
c:\users\x\test\A\file2.txt, last modified date
:
etc.
```

I would greatly appreciate any help on solving this problem. Any recommendations on a good Powershell reference book would also be appreciated so I can properly learn this subject.

I am using Powershell on Windows 7 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning this line

> ```
> $file.fullname, $file.lastwritetime | out-file -append c:\users\x\desktop\output.txt
> ```

You are using array notation when you use the comma not in a string. What this does is send two elements down the pipe *one at a time* to the `Out-File` cmdlet. If you were to type out `$file.fullname, $file.lastwritetime` without the `Out-File` you would see two separate lines in your console as well. You *could* fix this by making it a string....

```
"$($file.fullname), $($file.lastwritetime)" | out-file -append c:\users\x\desktop\output.txt
```

However, since you are trying to make a CSV anyway I would suggest you look at `Export-CSV` anyway. Just use `select-object` to get the properties you need.

```
$path="c:\users\x\desktop\TEST"
$csv = "c:\users\x\desktop\output.txt"
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse |
    Select-Object fullname,lastwritetime |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $csv
```

Comment: Thank you, Matt. This certainly works, and the second suggestion to use "select-object" is the best solution for my need.

Comment: Is there a faster way to generate this listing when I have a file structure that has approximately 1 million files in it? The directory structure is on a network, and why the above technique works, it runs incredibly slow in this case. Works great on my local drive though. Is this simply too many files to try to use powershell for?